# Paste string to ms-ds-consistencyGUID attribute

Tags: powershell, scripting, guid

I would like to automate the completion of the attribute ms-ds-consistencyGUID in my AD from a string gathered in a .txt file.

I am able to convert the string to a GUID but I eventually get a different output in my AD. Here is my code.

```
$mykey = Get-Content C:\...\file.txt
```

The value of my key is "AD E9 8A 79 0B F1 5B 4D AB 5F 5C 29 DA 5B 85 7D"

Then I remove the spaces and convert the string to a GUID

```
[guid]$GUIDkey = $mykey.replace(" ","")
```

Once I am ok with that I send the whole thing in my AD :

```
Set-Aduser -Identity MY_USER -Add @{"ms-ds-ConsistencyGUID" = $GUIDkey}
```

It works but the value is different.

Have you guys any idea what am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Casting to `[guid]` creates a property `.Guid`, so you might try `Set-Aduser -Identity MY_USER -Add @{"ms-ds-ConsistencyGUID" = $GUIDkey.Guid}`

Answer (score 1):

Your operation is likely working. How you are retrieving the data from AD is where the inconsistency may lie.

If you query the value using `Get-ADUser`, it will return a byte array rather than a guid. In that case, you can do a simple conversion:

```
$a = Get-ADUser -Identity MY_USER -Properties 'ms-ds-consistencyguid'
$a.'ms-ds-consistencyguid' -as [guid] # Converts byte array to guid
```

If you are looking at the value in the AD attribute editor, you will see the value in the hex X2 format. This will appear to be your original string before the space replacement. You can verify from `Get-ADUser` that your AD data matches your original string by converting each byte into the hex X2 format and then joining the resulting X2 array elements together with a space.

```
$a = Get-ADUser -Identity MY_USER -Properties 'ms-ds-consistencyguid'
$x2 = foreach ($c in $a.'ms-ds-consistencyguid') { 
         "{0:X2}" -f $c
      } 
$x2 -Join " "
```

Answer (score 1):

I gather the content of my `.txt` file then turn the string into an array and process it so I get the expected result. Finally I set my user's account. And it all works great:

```
$mykey = (Get-Content C:\(...)\FILE.txt).Split(" ")

[guid]$myGUID = -join ($($mykey[-13..-16])+$($mykey[-11..-12])+$($mykey[-9..-10])+$($mykey[8..15]))

Set-Aduser -Identity USER -Add @{"ms-ds-consistencyGUID" = $myGUID}
```